1986's-1998 movie, with swords, Guns, magic ball weapons, and super speed walk
I'm looking for a martial arts Syfy or TNT channel b-movie from the 1986s to 1998s about good and evil. The movie looked like it was shot in one location. It looked kind of dark industrial complex. The movie had an great graphic and was visually appealing. Which leads me to believe it was made early 90's.      
Plot: A bad guy (I thought it was Christopher Lambert but most likely not I checked his wiki page before posting this) who was given an assignment to kill 5 chosen heroes by his boss. Before their destiny is revealed to them and their powers awaken. (The bad guy character wielded a sword I believe.) 
After killing the first of the heroes he is made good. I cannot remember how or by who or what. Also the scene has him in a street or alley way and I believe it was raining. Then I believe a light hit him turning him good. 
He then seeks out the remaining four to train them to fight against his evil boss and other assassins like he formally was. I believe the four were two females and two males or three males and one female. One I think one was an Asian male. There was also a cool training fight scene on water.
After training the four heroes to use their hidden strength or power he gives them each a weapon only they can use, which I thought it was like a magic ball weapon that maybe had powers of the elements. I believe water, fire, wind, and earth.
In the final battle the former bad guy faces his old boss in sword combat. As the four other heroes face off against the other hitch-men assassins and destroy them with the ball weapons. Not sure how the weapons were used.
I don't remember the end.
Another detail in the movie when they moving at super speeds, the special effect show it as slow motion walking with large steps with blurs behind him.
Release/Broadcast year: Not sure but I guess mid 90s to 98s.
Country: It appears western to me, so maybe US, Canada or UK but not sure.
Language: English
Colour/Black and White: It was in colour.

This is Invincible, a made for TV movie. 
The scene you discuss (wherein he becomes 'good') can be viewed here.
The weapons were indeed elemental, and the warriors themselves are the manifestation of the elements. 

"Mortal Kombat" (1995)
Your description is similar to this movie. It is a B-movie from 1995, Christopher Lambert is in it, there are slow motion scenes in the movie.
Trailer:



You can find the complete movie on YouTube.

Sorry the movie was not Mortal Combat.
